# How to insert a button into each row of a Tabulator table, using data from said row

Tags: angular, tabulator

I'm using the latest version of tabulator-tables (4.2 from their site) and am trying to insert a button into a separate column for each item, that will route to a unique route based off the item ID.  So eg:
if each item has an ID and a name, I want to display the Name in one column, and then a button that will route to something like 'details/{{id}}'.  I am also on Angular7 at the moment.  My Angular skills with interacting with the DOM are somewhat weak, which I think is what is preventing me from solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do something like this.

```
<div class="card-block">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Project Name</th>
        <th>Material ID</th>
        <th>Unit</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Total Quantity</th>
          <th>Edit</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let project of projects">
        <td>{{ project.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ project.material_projects.material_id}}</td>
        <td>{{ project.material_projects.unit }}</td>
        <td>{{ project.material_projects.quantity }}</td>
        <td>{{ project.material_projects.total }}</td>
<td><i [routerLink]="['/project', project.id]">edit</i></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Then your router would need to reflect that path as

```
path: project/:id
```

This will loop through the array projects and for each will display the data. When the icon that says edit is pressed it will navigate to a page with the corresponding Id for that item. I have never really used that table package but this would be how it's done normally. Hope this will give some guidance.